# Mysql: Selecting distinct row and showing the selected id. details will show below

Tags: mysql

i have problem on using group by and distinct. when using group by, id cant be shown. but if usingn distinct. it will shown all id and product id.
i want to use distinct product id and id will shown one of it below using random.
`select id,distinct(product id),cost from price order by rand()`

This will be the data.

| id | product id | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 6 |
| 5 | 3 | 4 |
| 6 | 3 | 3 |
| 7 | 3 | 1 |

After query will shown this.

| id | product id | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 4 | 2 | 6 |
| 5 | 3 | 4 |

Comment: you want to have the right id of product id or it can be incremented order from 1?

Comment: What is it that's supposed to be random? Price? your desired result look like the row with highest price by product

Comment: Do you want to have one random row per product saving id-price relation for selected row? If so then what is MySQL version?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, 
-- enumerate rows in each group with the same product id, randomly
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY RAND()) rn
    FROM tablename
)
SELECT id, product_id, price
FROM cte
-- select only 1st (random) row from each group
WHERE rn = 1;
```

?

Comment: Hello @Akina, it will be great if you will add some details about what you did or how did this solve user's query then it will be great.

Comment: @Leothelion This query do the operation which OP needs in. It enumerates thу rows in each group with the same product_id in random order then takes only 1st row from each group. I do not see what can be not clear in this query..

Comment: thank you for your response but if i am newbie and not able to get your query at once but if you will add little bit details about it then it will be easy to understand, right? It may be easy for you or for experienced but someone with early stage, then mate. I was just asking but its ok if you don't see it useful.

Comment: @Leothelion Usually, a person who does not understand the answer, first of all tries to study the documentation and still understand. There are those who do not even try to study theory, and limit themselves only to questions - such people deprive themselves of the opportunity to get a base for new knowledge. And it's harder for them to apply the facts they've learned, because they've learned "how" but not "why so".

Comment: Agree with all your point but i just wanted to say that it will be great if you will add little bit detail, nothing else but ok. Thank you for your response. :)

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your answer** by editing it, not to the comment section

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  (SELECT id FROM price WHERE product_id = p.product_id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) AS id,
  p.product_id,
  (SELECT price FROM price WHERE product_id = p.product_id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) AS price
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM price) p;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/rZY6AA-j